# How to return an array in C into python?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

I have been working on a selection sort with C extension on python, which aimed to intake a list in python, sort using C code and return a sorted list in python.  Sounds simple, but I just could not get the value of the sorted list correct in python, as I would get a value of 1 when I was trying to print the sorted list.
Here is my code in C:

```
#include <Python.h>

int selectionSort(int array[], int N){
    int i, j, min_element;
    
    for (i = 0; i < N-1; i++) {
        min_element = i;
        for (j = i+1; j < N; j++)
        if (array[j] < array[min_element])
        min_element = j;
        int temp = array[min_element];
        array[min_element] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
    }
    
    return *array;

}



static PyObject* selectSort(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject* list;
    int *array, N;
    
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &list))
        return NULL;
    N = PyObject_Length(list);
    if (N < 0)
        return NULL;
    array = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int *) * N);
    if (array == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for (int index = 0; index < N; index++) {
        PyObject *item;
        item = PyList_GetItem(list, index);
        if (!PyFloat_Check(item))
            array[index] = 0;
        array[index] = PyFloat_AsDouble(item);
    }
    return Py_BuildValue("i", selectionSort(array, N));
}

static PyMethodDef myMethods[] = {
    { "selectSort", selectSort, METH_VARARGS, "..." },
    { NULL, NULL, 0, NULL }
};


static struct PyModuleDef myModule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "myModule",
    "Test Module",
    -1,
    myMethods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_myModule(void)
{
    return PyModule_Create(&myModule);
}
```

Here is the command line I executed:

```
>>> import myModule
>>> unsortedList = [1, 4, 3, 90, 22, 34, 32]
>>> sortedList = myModule.selectSort(unsortedList)
>>> print(sortedList)
1
```

Anyone has any ideas on this? I would really appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: If you return `int` you return just a single value; if at all, you need to return a pointer (to a newly allocated array). However, currently you are sorting the array *in place*, so you should see the results directly in python if you do *not* re-assign the array there. And I recommend to stay with that, that spares you memory management issues from in between C (manual malloc/free) and Python (automatic).

Comment: Should I assume that you are just experimenting with python extensions? Because otherwise – why wouldn't you sort in python directly? And if you sort in C, there's [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) already. Why re-invent the wheel? And selection sort isn't pretty efficient anyway...

Comment: @Aconcagua yes I'm just experimenting with python extensions, I believe that this method is more efficient when we are sorting an enormous amount of data?

Comment: Selection sort is `O(n²)` on worst case as well as on *average* – so that's anything else than efficient especially on *large* data sets! Heap or merge sort are both `O(n*log(n))` in worst case, so perform far better, quick sort is even better on average, but can in worst case fall back to `O(n²)` – which is avoided in intro-sort, a hybrid of quick and (usually) heap sort. Intro-sort is the one used by C++ standard library, by the way...

Answer (score 0):

Just change return type from `int` to `int*` and return with `return array`, not `return *array`.

Comment: Thanks! but which int should I change? I'm a bit confused (sorry I'm a beginner at coding...)

Comment: The first method, `selectionSort()`. Just do `[return type]*`

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing that way – it suggests a new array being returned, but instead the one being passed to is modified in place. As that cannot fail, I'd rather propose returning `void`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using int* slectionSort and it returned a bunch of numbers (which looks like the address of the array), but not the actual value of it... Here is my command line: 
`>>> print(sortedList)
2818048`

Comment: Show me your `return` statement.

Comment: @TechTycho sorry for my late reply here is my return statement now:
`return array;`

Comment: `*array` always points to the first element of an array. So you should return the array, not the first element with the array. `return *array` in the code you reported will just output one since it is the first element of the array. Now `int selectionSort()` will just return an int. We want an array so type `int* selectionSort()`.